# getting index on NSIndexPath on UICollectionView

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I have an array of items for UICollectionView(with 2 columns and 3 rows) and  I want to access it with the indexPath but I cant made it

If I use `indexPath.row` or `indexPath.item` I get 0,1,0,1,0,1.

If I use `indexPath.section` I get 0,0,1,1,2,2

What I want is 0,1,2,3,4,5,6

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

MenuCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
//cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor ];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor ];

UIImage* imagenprobar =[UIImage imageNamed: [imagenes objectAtIndex: indexPath.item]];
[cell.imagen setImage: imagenprobar];




cell.label.text = [textos objectAtIndex: indexPath.item];

return cell;
```

}

Comment: indexPath.row must return what you want (0,1,2,3,4,5,6). Make sure you return 1 for "numberOfSectionsInCollectionView"

Comment: Use like this as your column is 2 so (indexpath.section*2)+indexPath.row

Comment: @THILINACHÁMINHewagama I cant do that, since i need 3 rows in my CollectionView if I return 1 only 1 row is showed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `(indexpath.section*yourTotalColumn)+indexPath.row` to calculate exact index of array for UICollectionView.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   ......................

   .......................

   //Now calculate index of array (datasource) Note : here column is 2.
   NSInteger index = (indexpath.section*2)+indexPath.row
   cell.label.text = [textos objectAtIndex:index];

   return cell;
```

}